# How to parse mibs for trap message for snmp4j

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp4j, snmpd, snmptrapd

I enabled Snmptrap on Windows and I got trap messages from remote devices. Following describes result.

```
 2016-10-25 10:19:02 <UNKNOWN> [UDP: [172.16.11.250]:62451->[0.0.0.0]:0]:
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (287374) 0:47:53.74    SNMPv2-MIB::snmpTrapOID.0 = OID: IF-MIB::linkDown       IF-MIB::ifIndex.116 = INTEGER: 116
IF-MIB::ifAdminStatus.116 = INTEGER: up(1)      IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.116 = INTEGER: down(2)     IF-MIB::ifName.116 = STRING: ge-1/0/1
```

I also got trap message via snmp4j. Following is my code and result.

```
Vector<VariableBinding> vbVect = event.getPDU().getVariableBindings();      
for (VariableBinding vb : vbVect) {
    System.out.println(vb.getOid() + " = " + vb.getVariable());
}
```

result

```
1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0 = 1:27:14.38
1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.4.1.0 = 1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.1.116 = 116
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7.116 = 1
1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8.116 = 2
1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1.116 = ge-1/0/1
```

My question is how can I get trap message after mib parse, just like output on windows?
There are many trap oid on my devices. Should I put them on a file and and parse oid via this file? Or Should I load mibs through snmp4j?

Is there any method can do this? What`s the best practice for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve OIDs based on MIB modules definitions you'll have to use libraries like **SMI4J**, **Mibble** or some others that are capable of parsing MIB files (SMIv1/SMIv2 formats).

You can also use commercial products like **NetDecision MIB Manager** that allow you to convert several MIB files to normalized file in XML format. After that all you have to do is load XML file using any DOM parser. No need to parse complex ASN.1 (SMI) structures and deal with dependencies. Also you don't have to worry about malformed MIB files and error handling.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will look into Mibble.

Answer (score 0):

SNMP4J-SMI-PRO will directly integrate with SNMP4J and provides MIB parsing capabilities. OID to object name mapping and value formatting is ready-to-use with already existing SNMP4J code.